# angular 5 material - form fields stuck at 180px

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I've created a form in a dialog using material forms, but I can't seem to get the inputs to be wider than 180px despite following numerous examples including https://material.angular.io/components/input/example.

I'm sure this is a pretty standard CSS thing, but I don't have that sort of brain so I cant figure out the problem.

Does anyone have a serious / non-trivial example that works??

Here's mine:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{title}}</h1>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form novalidate #f="ngForm" class="form-full-width">
    <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="name" matInput placeholder="Name">
      <mat-hint>Enter a unique name.</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="data.description" name="description" matInput placeholder="Description"></textarea>
      <mat-hint>You should describe the purpose/use of this thing.</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

CSS :

```
.form-full-width {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width:100%;
}

.input-full-width {
    width:800px;
}

.mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
    width: auto;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems like it's something to do with View Encapsulation.  This thread explains it:  https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4034 but changing encapsulation for the component causes all sorts of compile failures.

This article gave me the correct solution:https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

I'll move my style to global scope...

```
.formFieldWidth480 .mat-form-field-infix {
   width: 480px;
}
```

and in the component that opens the dialog:

```
this.newDialog = this.dialog.open(NewDialogComponent,
  {
    width: '650px', height: '550px',
    data : newThing,
    panelClass : "formFieldWidth480"
  });
```

I hope this saves someone else the day I lost...

Comment: such a big thing for that!!!!! Thx, but still remains like a workaround for me... why 180px :$

Answer (score 37):

can you try using

```
mat-form-field {
width: 100%;
}
```

I had the same issue in a `mat-card`, this worked for me.

Comment: This works great.  I put it in the component's SCSS

Comment: This worked for me "@angular/core": "^8.2.14" and "@angular/material": "^8.2.3"

Comment: Should that be an element name or a class name? I played with it and they both select the elements. 

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to define a width (e.g. if you are using flex-grow) you can also define "min-width: 0" or whatever value fits your needs.

Answer (score 18):

Just like Jonesie said, this behavior is related to View Encapsulation. In this context `.mat-form-field-infix` takes `180px` as default value [probably beacause of this](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/9eeb4b5aa0473c0815a73bfe3c2ed6164d86a3b3/src/material/form-field/form-field.scss#L13). The `auto` value lets the browser calculates the width instead of puting hardcoded value. The `!important` declarations forces the style override for this.
I am using `!important` since it complies with the rules for the use of this property. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation. CSS answers that use `!important` are like answers that use `sudo`; they should explain why the answer needs that, and what the risks of using it are.

Comment: Ng Deep is now deprecated.

Comment: There is no need to use `!important`.
And use `ViewEncapsulation.None` instead of `::ng-deep`.
Or if you want to modify all selects just put it in the `styles.css` file.

Answer (score 8):

It's that .mat-form-field.mat-form-field in the css that's causing an issue.  As soon as I removed that, I could control the widths with .input-full-width width setting.  I set up a demo here: [StackBlitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8ule5)

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{title}}</h1>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form novalidate #f="ngForm" class="form-full-width">
    <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="name" matInput placeholder="Name">
      <mat-hint>Enter a unique name.</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="data.description" name="description" matInput placeholder="Description"></textarea>
      <mat-hint>You should describe the purpose/use of this thing.</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

```css
.form-full-width {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width:100%;
}

.input-full-width {
    width:800px;
}

/* .mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
    width: auto;
} */
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I only added that override for mat-form-field after reading in a bug post for @angular/material.  It was a long shot.  Im still having the same problem.  It looks like the fixed width of 180px is coming from mat-form-field-infix but even setting an inline style doesnt seem to override this.  Maybe becuase this is in a dialog...

Answer (score 7):

The solution I found was [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/8lkfyl/angulars_material_matformfield_makes_my_input/) into general `style.css`

```
mat-form-field {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  width: calc(100% - 2.5rem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
  width:800px !important;
}
```

This should work fine.Not sure if it can be done without custom CSS.

Comment: NG deep is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, fixed it with.
But still no idea why this issue is happening...

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
  width: 100%;
}
```