# How to change mat-form-field width in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-form-field

I wanna change the width of the field I am using angular material , I tried adding css to the global style.css and also on the component.css but it does not work . Any idea thanks. I have sample fields below . thank you

#mycss (what I have tried)

```
.mat-form-field-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 160%;
}
```

#HTML

```
 <div fxLayout="column">
                         <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="24px">
                          <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex>
                              <mat-label>Label 1</mat-label>
  
                            </mat-form-field>
                          </div>
                          <div fxFlex></div>
                        </div>

                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="24px">
                          <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex>
                              <mat-label>Label 2</mat-label>
                              <mat-select formControlName="choice" required>
                            </mat-form-field>
                          </div>
                          <div fxFlex></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376554/angular-5-material-form-fields-stuck-at-180px

Comment: Remove that styles from `component.css` and add it in globle `style.css` and refer this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376554/angular-5-material-form-fields-stuck-at-180px

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying `.mat-form-field-flex` class in your `css` to `mat-form-field`

```css
mat-form-field {
  width: 300px !important
}
```

Comment: still the same , does not work , i tried putting on global style,css and on component css

Comment: Global style will only help, when modifying the style of an inner element inside a child component, but in your case, you only need you change the host element of the child component

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering why setting *width* only works for enlarging: *mat-form-field* and or *input* in Angular Material appear to have set a *min-width* by default which prevents reducing the width.

In order to reduce the width you must also use:

```
mat-form-field {
    min-width: 1px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your css file just add this css

```
:host::ng-deep.mat-form-field {
   width : 100px; //enter whatever width you want
}
```

Comment: Percentage widths are very useful when it comes to sizing elements relative to something else (browser size for instance). You can have your page dynamically change to fit different circumstances. Pixels on the other hand are useful when you need precision sizes that won't change on you

Comment: I see , but why does the css only works in my global style css but not in components Sir?

Comment: I did put it on my css component but its affecting others

Comment: Then you can just add new class to mat-form-field tag and mention that class in your css like
      `:host::ng-deep.mat-form-field .your_class_name {
   width : 100px; //enter whatever width you want
}`